# replacing Date in String with some text in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, datetime

I have text like

```
input_string = " - 01 APRIL 2018 - ING000038985695286069"
```

i want to replace date in the string with text like DD or DATE

```
output_string = "- DD/DATE - ING000038985695286069"
```

So far, i am able to extract date from the string using

```
import datefinder
matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(input_string))
if len(matches) > 0:
    date = matches[0]
    print(date)
```

But how to get my output is my Question.

Comment: You'll have to post your code for `find_dates`, but I suppose you're using regular expression there. If so, just use `re.sub` instead of `match` and it'll work fine.

Comment: find_dates is a method inside datefinder library.  Can you show me what you are telling

Answer (score 1):

The datefinder is cool for parsing the dates out of the text, but you can omit the library and just use regular expressions (**if** the dates are always in the shown format).

```
import re

result = re.sub('\s(\d*\s\w*\s\d*)\s', ' DATE ', input_string)
```

Regular expression breakdown:

- `\s` matches a space
- `(` start capturing the text
- `\d*` match any digit as many times as possible
- `\s` match exactly one space character
- `\w*` match as many word characters as possible (actually also matches numbers)
- `\s` again one space
- `\d*` again as many digits as possible
- `)` end capturing
- `\s` match one space

**UPDATE**
The datefinder package can be used as follows to find all dates:

```
dates_regex = datefinder.DateFinder().DATE_REGEX
dates_regex.sub('DATE ', input_string)
```

> Note that this solution still uses the package, but doesn't actually do what you expect it to. It finds number sequences and replaces them too.
>   I would **strongly** suggest you build your own regex to cover exactly your needs.

Comment: Hey, it is not covering all my casses, if input string is 'CIwr UNdfdIadfdN ghw dfsdfdsfsT dgsggafqfe NO 9561364454 DATED 03-JULY-2018' it is not returning me any date. so my date is not going to be in same format every time. i want to extract any date from string as datefinder return

Comment: I'll pull the datefinder package and check out how we can do it with that.